# Blank page after fresh phpBB 3.1.3 install

Tags: php, mysql, phpbb, phpbb3

I've got a problem after installing phpBB Version 3.1.3 on my webspace. Everytime when I access the admin panel out of the installer after a fresh installation the admin panel works perfectly - until I log out and / or delete the /install/ directory (wich is required). Then, when I try to access the /adm/ directory again, I get a blank page. Enabling PHP debug resolves in no errors what so ever.

I already googled my a** off, trying to find a solution or even a useful hint to this problem. It also seems to be very common - but I couldn't find a solution yet. Anyone ever got the same problem and knows a solution or at least some suggestions?

My webspace runs PHP version 5.3.27 and MySQL / MySQLi 5.1.73

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please check error log of apache or whatever web server you are using. Sometimes errors are not shown in front end. If nothing is there then check for php error log files.

Comment: Network monitor if your Browser dev tools returns HTTP 200 and a really empty page or an other status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `/adm` directory of phpBB is deliberately not accessible by typing the url without a valid session id for security purposes, you need to use the link from the site which includes your current session id as a `GET` parameter.

Also when you log out and then back in again you are assigned a new id number.

Comment: That was indeed my mistake. It took me a while but I finally figured that out myself a few days later. Makes perfect sense, too. So for the record: You're right, of course. Thanks for the answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

phpBB Version 3.1.3 requires PHP version 5.3.3+
Also you may have not enabled the error reporting. You can set PHP error reporting on by writing the following lines;

If php.ini,

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL
display_errors = On
```

If .htaccess,

```
php_value error_reporting       2039
php_flag  display_errors        on
```